# mongoose call child method after populating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a method that deletes all of a users files.

```
//User Schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    files:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'File' }]
});

//File Schema
var fileSchema = Schema({
    owner: { required: true, type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    filename: {type:String,required:true},
});
fileSchema.methods.deleteFromDisk = function () {
    //delete function
};
```

How can I run the `deleteFromDisk` on all of a users files? I am currently populating like this:

```
User.populate('files').exec(function (err, user) {
    console.log(user.files); //Shows files as json
    user.files.map(file=> {
        file.deleteFromDisk(); //ERROR - fileSchema.deleteFromDisk is not a function
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you really want two sets of pointers `user.files` and `files.owner` as they may get out of sync? If you in doubt you can read [this part of the mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children).

Comment: If you want to delete records from the database you need to call `update` operation... Don't know why you are using `populate` here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Where you defining **User** and **File** model? It can be the cause of the problem if you defined a schema instance methods after you define a model.

Example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const assert = require('assert');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const wrongSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const correctSchema = Schema({
  name: String
});

// define model before it's schema instance methods
const Wrong = mongoose.model('Wrong', wrongSchema);

wrongSchema.methods.customInstanceMethod = function () {
  console.log('My name is', this.name);
};

correctSchema.methods.customInstanceMethod = function () {
  console.log('My name is', this.name);
};

// define model after it's schema instance methods
const Correct = mongoose.model('Correct', correctSchema);

const iCorrect = new Correct({ name: 'correct' });
assert(iCorrect.customInstanceMethod); // it passes this assert
iCorrect.customInstanceMethod();  // => My name is correct

const iWrong = new Wrong({ name: 'wrong' });
assert(iWrong.customInstanceMethod); // => AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == true
iWrong.customInstanceMethod();  // => TypeError: iWrong.customInstanceMethod is not a function
```